# React-Table useTable is not defined (no Node.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm building a React app without Node.js (i.e. pulling all JS as unpkg script tags and running it natively in the browser) and am using `react-table`.  However, I keep getting this error when using this code snippet from the [demo](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/quick-start#final-result):

```
function Table({columns, data}) {
    // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    })
...
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: useTable is not defined
```

My JS files are:

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@7.7.0/dist/react-table.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

I've [read](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/discussions/3263) that this issue resolves with `react-table` version 7.7.0 but this is the exact version I'm using.

EDIT: Complete code from the demo that I'm trying to run:

App.js:

```
function App() {
   const data = React.useMemo(
     () => [
       {
         col1: 'Hello',
         col2: 'World',
       },
       {
         col1: 'react-table',
         col2: 'rocks',
       },
       {
         col1: 'whatever',
         col2: 'you want',
       },
     ],
     []
   )
 
   const columns = React.useMemo(
     () => [
       {
         Header: 'Column 1',
         accessor: 'col1', // accessor is the "key" in the data
       },
       {
         Header: 'Column 2',
         accessor: 'col2',
       },
     ],
     []
   )
 
   const {
     getTableProps,
     getTableBodyProps,
     headerGroups,
     rows,
     prepareRow,
   } = useTable({ columns, data })
 
   return (
     <table {...getTableProps()} style={{ border: 'solid 1px blue' }}>
       <thead>
         {headerGroups.map(headerGroup => (
           <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
             {headerGroup.headers.map(column => (
               <th
                 {...column.getHeaderProps()}
                 style={{
                   borderBottom: 'solid 3px red',
                   background: 'aliceblue',
                   color: 'black',
                   fontWeight: 'bold',
                 }}
               >
                 {column.render('Header')}
               </th>
             ))}
           </tr>
         ))}
       </thead>
       <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
         {rows.map(row => {
           prepareRow(row)
           return (
             <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
               {row.cells.map(cell => {
                 return (
                   <td
                     {...cell.getCellProps()}
                     style={{
                       padding: '10px',
                       border: 'solid 1px gray',
                       background: 'papayawhip',
                     }}
                   >
                     {cell.render('Cell')}
                   </td>
                 )
               })}
             </tr>
           )
         })}
       </tbody>
     </table>
   )
 }
```

Index.js:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

makeData.js:

```
const range = len => {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  return arr
}

const newPerson = () => {
  const statusChance = Math.random()
  return {
    firstName: "Scott",
    lastName: "H",
    age: Math.floor(Math.random() * 30),
    visits: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    progress: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
    status:
      statusChance > 0.66
        ? 'relationship'
        : statusChance > 0.33
        ? 'complicated'
        : 'single',
  }
}

function makeData(...lens) {
  const makeDataLevel = (depth = 0) => {
    const len = lens[depth]
    return range(len).map(d => {
      return {
        ...newPerson(),
        subRows: lens[depth + 1] ? makeDataLevel(depth + 1) : undefined,
      }
    })
  }

  return makeDataLevel()
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>React Local</title>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="//unpkg.com/react-is/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@7.7.0/react-table.css" crossorigin>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-table@7.7.0/dist/react-table.development.js" crossorigin></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel" src="makeData.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="app.js'"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="index.js'"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you share complete and reproducible code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Was listed in the demo I linked, but have amended my OP accordingly.

Comment: You may need to reference a `ReactTable` namespace when using via script tag. https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/182

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, this did the trick!  I had to use `window.ReactTable.useTable`.  Thanks for finding that issue, I somehow missed it when reading through!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to DrewReese, `useTable` must be referenced as `window.ReactTable.useTable` when using `react-table` via a script tag from the unpkg CDN:

```
function Table({columns, data}) {
    // Use the state and functions returned from useTable to build your UI
    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
    } = window.ReactTable.useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    })
...
```